# How to register identical WCF endpoints under different Subdomains?

Tags: https, netsh, wcf

### How do I have two services offer identical WCF endpoints under different subdomains?

I have two Services, each trying offering WCF Endpoints to consumers in my network:

- Service 1: https://subdomain1.domain/Service
- Service 2: https://subdomain2.domain/Service

I also have registered the following entries via `netsh http add urlacl`:

- netsh http add urlacl url="https://subdomain1.domain:443/Service" user="NETWORK SERVICE"
- netsh http add urlacl url="https://subdomain2.domain:443/Service" user="NETWORK SERVICE"

(Note: I also tried registering `url="https://+443/Service"`)

Both Services are running as Network Service.

### The Problem:

I can start Service1, no problem. The endpoint is available at the subdomain1-address. But, service 2 cannot register his endpoint with the followig error message:

> Failed to listen on prefix 'https://+:443/Service/' because it conflicts with an existing registration on the machine.

No mention of subdomain1 or 2 in the error message.

How can I register two services on the same Port (443), but with different subdomains?